# Extract string between two strings using Regexp in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, text, extract

I try to extract text between `[%L10n.msg('` and `')%]` in Perl, so for example if I have code like `[%L10n.msg('foo')%]`, I would like to get **foo**.

I have working script for it, as you can see it below, but it is buggy and it breaks encoding as you can see.

I would like to know what is wrong with that script and how to fix it.

**My Regexp script:**

```
my (@L10n) = $content_from_file =~ /\[\%L10n\.msg\('(.*)'\)\%\]/g;
```

**$content_from_file:**

```
    <div class="detail-trash">
          <span class="blog-article-social-net social-net-fb">
             <svg class="svg-icon-facebook">
                <use xlink:href="[%domain.url_media%]/images/svg-sprite.svg#svg-icon-facebook"></use>
             </svg>
             [%L10n.msg('Zdielať')%]
          </span>
       <span class="previews-counter">Počet hodnotení: [%product.rating_votes%]</span>
       <a href="#" title="[%L10n.msg('Zobraziť recenzie')%]" class="previews-btn js-previews-btn">[%L10n.msg('Zobraziť recenzie')%]</a>
    </div>
```

**Current result:**

```
Zdiela\x{165}
Zobrazi\x{165} recenzie')%]\" class=\"previews-btn js-previews-btn\">[%L10n.msg('Zobrazi\x{165} recenzie
```

**Requested result:**

```
Zdielať
Zobraziť recenzie
Zobraziť recenzie
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regex `.*` is greedy. This means it will try to match the longest string possible.
Change it to `.*?` so that it is not greedy. Then it will match the shortest string possible.

```
my @L10n = $content_from_file =~ /\[%L10n\.msg\('(.*?)'\)%\]/g;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but encoding is still broken.

Comment: @tomsk The encoding is an entirely different issue. It depends on many things like your terminal (is it expecting UTF-8 or some other encoding) and the encoding of the initial string `$content_from_file`. That is something you'll have work out.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to fix your matching problem is to make the `.*` part of your regex non-greedy, by adding a `?` to the end.

Your encoding problem is harder to address as it depends on the encoding of your data file and how you are reading the data into your file. So we would need more information.

This version works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $content_from_file = <<END_OF_TXT;
    <div class="detail-trash">
          <span class="blog-article-social-net social-net-fb">
             <svg class="svg-icon-facebook">
                <use xlink:href="[%domain.url_media%]/images/svg-sprite.svg#svg-icon-facebook"></use>
             </svg>
             [%L10n.msg('Zdielať')%]
          </span>
       <span class="previews-counter">Počet hodnotení: [%product.rating_votes%]</span>
       <a href="#" title="[%L10n.msg('Zobraziť recenzie')%]" class="previews-btn js-previews-btn">[%L10n.msg('Zobraziť recenzie')%]</a>
    </div>
END_OF_TXT

my (@L10n) = $content_from_file =~ /\[\%L10n\.msg\('(.*?)'\)\%\]/g;
say Dumper @L10n;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = 'Zdielať';
$VAR2 = 'Zobraziť recenzie';
$VAR3 = 'Zobraziť recenzie';
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this regexp for you

```
(?:\[%L10n.msg\(')([A-Za-zť ]+)
```

It match what you need but maybe you need to tweak if for Slovakian characters?
The result is in group1

You can take a look at it here.

https://regex101.com/r/hHbNEe/1/

Comment: Yea, but it can contain even HTML code inside L10n :)